# banshee sync playlsits lost order in device

Tags: banshee

I have a playlist manually ordered, also I synchronize it with my Android, everything works fine, but when I reproduce the list from the android, the playlist is sorted alphabetically.

Also if I open it with a text editor I can confirm that the list is ordered this way. Why is this happening ? is a bug or may be I have to configure something in banshee ?

thank you.

Comment: Where is the playlist out of order, on your Android device or in Banshee after importing from the Android device? If it's out of order on the mobile, how are you syncing the playlist?